# How to open whole html page as modal?

Tags: angularjs, mean-stack

I'm very new to angularjs and currently studying mean stack. I'm using this code to open an html page then getting the id of clicked user.

```
<a href="/edit/{{ person._id }}">
<button type="button" ng-show="management.editAccess" class="btn btn-primary">Edit</button>
</a>
```

But I want to open my html as a modal, I tried this method here http://plnkr.co/edit/Y7jDj2hORWmJ95c96qoG?p=preview but it doesn't show the html, Please help me on how to open my whole html as modal.

Answer (score 0):

You need to `$http.get` the template in html and then using `$sce` render it.

```
 <button data-toggle="modal" data-target="#theModal" ng-click="get()">get</button>

<div id="theModal" class="modal fade text-center">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div ng-bind-html="trustedHtml"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

JS:

```
 $scope.get = function() {
        $http({
            method: 'GET',
            url: 'Lab6.html',

        })
            .then(function successCallback(data){

                $scope.data = data.data;
                console.log($scope.data);
                $scope.trustedHtml = $sce.trustAsHtml($scope.data);
                },
             function errorCallback(response){
                console.log(response);
                console.log('error');
            });
    }
```

Here is working plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/SdCAep1dDH8UcpprwDH6?p=preview

Also I would argue that you should probably be using Angular UI Bootstrap to create your modal dialogs http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/

Here is a cut down version of how to open a modal using Angular UI Bootrstrap:

```
$scope.open = function (vehicle) {

  var modalInstance = $modal.open({
    templateUrl: 'myModalContent.html',
    resolve: {
      items: function () {
        return $scope.items;
      }
    }
  });

};
```

Comment: it's working for my pages with MainCtrl but my edit.html has editCtrl, how should I resolve this

Comment: @InUtero Use ui.bootstrap (in which You'll be able to pass $scope to other controller) - read documentation about ui.bootstrap.modal,